# Merge all lines into one and add a specific character

Tags: notepad++

I have the following list:

> 10019440
>    10019545
>    10019545
>    10019553
>    10020262
>    10020587
>    10020939

I want it to look like

> '10019440','10019545','10019545','10019553','10020262','10020587','10020939'

How do I do this in Notepad++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\R|\A)(\d+)`
- Replace with: `'$1',`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # start non capture group
  \R        # any kind of linebreak
 |          # OR
  \A        # beginning of file
)           # end group
(\d+)       # group 1, 1 or more digits
```

**Result for given example:**

```
'10019440','10019545','10019545','10019553','10020262','10020587','10020939',
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use search and replace, and look for line breaks - they are represented by the `\n` "character". Replace every line break with `', '`. It'll do it for all of your lines except for the first and the last, then you just put the single quotes on the beginning and the end.

Comment: You'll also need to select the "Extended" option in the replace dialog